# Binding Escape key (ESC) in Emacs running in Console (-nw)

Tags: emacs, elisp, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs23, emacs24

I am trying to bind the `ESC` key to a custom elisp function,

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<escape>") 'my-local-mode)
```

which works under X but does not when emacs is running in a termial. ESC acts as META. However I have tried evil mode and it is able to capture ESC (single ESC not M-ESC ESC). However digging thorugh the code I can not figure out where/how they did it. `describe-key` doesn't work. How can I bind single ESC press to call my function?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior seems fairly involved as it is in the core of emacs to have this translation: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html

The behavior in evil happens in the following file: http://gitorious.org/evil/evil/blobs/master/evil-core.el